# Most efficient way to trasform chars in multi span while maintaining html format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing a javascript library that animate a div with random chart entry. 
I need to trasform every char in to a div with maintain the html format. 
What is the most efficiently method to do this? 
Example:

```
<div class="base_container">Hi Elia,<br>what's your name?</div>
```

into:

```
<div class="base_container">
    <span id="char_1">H</span>
    <span id="char_2">i</span>
    <span id="char_3"> </span>
    <span id="char_4">E</span>
    <span id="char_5">l</span>
    <span id="char_6">i</span>
    <span id="char_7">a</span>
    <span id="char_8">,</span>
    <br>
    <span id="char_9">w</span>
    <span id="char_10">h</span>
    .
    .
    .
</div>
```

Thanks you in advance ! The hardest part is maintain the html format !

Comment: Are there only `<br>` tags inside, or anything else may appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accounts for any tags in HTML formatting, not `<br>` only:

```
    var i = 0,
        div = $('<div class="base_container">Hi Elia,<br>whats your <b>name</b>?</div>');

    function processContent(element){
        element.contents().each(function(){
            if(this.nodeType == 3){ 
                /* it's safe to process text nodes only */
                var content = this.textContent;
                content = content.replace(/./g, function(a){ return '<span id="char_' + ++i + '">' + a + '</span>'; })

                $(this).replaceWith($(content));
            }else{
                /* recursively process child nodes */
                return processContent($(this));
            }
        });
    }

    processContent(div);


    console.log(div.html());
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to tell you *how* to do this since that's not your question. The best way to approach this is to simply:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('base_container')[0];
var content = elem.innerHTML;
// Do some crazy stuff with regex and string parsing
elem.innerHTML = content;
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this that way:

```
var baseContainer = document.querySelector(".base_container");
var textParts = baseContainer.innerHTML.match(/<[^>]+>|&[a-z0-9]+;|./gi);

baseContainer.innerHTML = textParts.map(function (textPart, index) {
    return textPart.length > 1 ? textPart : "<div id='char_" + index + "'>" + textPart + "</div>";
}).join("");
```

Comment: This does not account for possible formatting like `<u>another tags</u>`

Comment: It supports tag nesting. Is that what you meant?

Comment: You're right, but it takes any `<whatever>` sequence as a HTML tag, which is not correct.

Comment: You're right, `<whatever>` in textNode shouldn't be treat as a tag (I've edited my answer). On the other hand, you can write your own tags in html so it's OK to have `<whatever>` in html (not created by `createTextNode`). In chrome it works 4 times faster than your approach.

Comment: Try it on this `"how would you deal with a < 10 and b > 13"` text. It may definitely work faster, but from my experience if you're solving any context related problem - use this context related approach. So if we're talking about HTML there is no better way to solve the problem than to use HTML-related approach. I may be wrong...

Comment: If you write something like this in html you will probably break your page. If you want to display `<` or `>` you must use html entities `&lt;` and `&gt;` or put this text as a textNode. In both situations `innerHTML` will return those symbols as html entities, and this part of regex `&[a-z0-9]+;` will find them and treat as one letter. I agree with you that your approach is cleaner and more elegant, but OP was asking for most efficient way :-)